# trouble adding checkboxes dynamically in QT

Tags: qt

My requirement: dynamically create check boxes based on the no.of lines in a text file loaded.

Below is my code :

```
QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
for(i=0;i<number_of_commands;i++)
{
    QCheckBox *dynamic = new QCheckBox(names[i]);
    dynamic->setChecked (true);
    lay->addWidget(dynamic);
}
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents_2->setLayout(lay);
```

I can see the correct number of check boxes but only first box is named that too with last name (i.e. `box1` is named with names[20] and all other boxes are empty)

Comment: hi all the code is working fine. Problem is with the names[i] array. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkboxes have no names (associated texts) because you do not set them. You can set it on construction, for example:

```
QCheckBox *dynamic = new QCheckBox("This is a check box");
```

The `setObjectName()` function you use is `QObject` (the base class) function, and it sets rather the object name, that has a different meaning.

Comment: thanks. after trying "new QCheckBox(names[i]);", i got 20 boxes but names are getting overridden for the first box. so names[20] is assigned to first box. remaining boxes are still empty. any help here?

Comment: @user3891367, hm, are you sure you use the same code as above?

Comment: @user3891367: I think you should accept vahancho's answer if it helped you... otherwise if you fixed your code in a different way and/or if the question has sense no more, then consider closing it