# Is there any way to add Chekboxes dynamically that I can access them and their checkstate out of their definition scope?

Tags: qt, checkbox, dynamic, qcheckbox

I want to add checkboxes dynamically. I found some links helpfull ,but each of them has a problem that I can't solve.

for example in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038075/trouble-adding-checkboxes-dynamically-in-qt) we can create & add `QCheckBox`es dynamically, but I can't access them out of their definition scope (for).

And another way is using `QListWidgetItem` with `setCheckState`. but It has a very big problem! when I click on the `CheckState`, it doesn't notice it and just focus on the Item that is focus is on it!!!! {in these links this problem is introduced but no solution: [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/1589-QListWidgetItem-with-checkboxes-detecting-when-state-changed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163516/qlistview-item-with-checkbox-selection-behavior) }

Is there any way to add Chekboxes dynamically that I can access them and their checkstate out of their definition scope?

Comment: can you show some code (what have you done so far)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save pointers to checkBoxes that you've created. For example to add `QVector<QCheckBox> checkBoxes;` to your widget and then append this pointers to vector.

Result code can look like this:

In header:

```
YourWidget : public QWidget {
....
QVector<QCheckBox*> checkboxes;
....
```

And in the source:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    QCheckBox *box = new QCheckBox;
    layout->addWidget(box);
    checkboxes.append(box);
}
```

So then you can get acces to your checkBoxes: `checkboxes[0]->setChecked(true);` or smth

And don't forget to release memory allocated for checkBoxes in destructor of you widget (you don't need to do this if you added them to layout)

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkboxes.size(); i++) {
    delete checkboxes[i];
}
```

Comment: You don't have to delete the objects in the destructor. They are automatically destroyed by Qt if you add them to a layout.

Comment: in line:  checkboxes.append(box);

Comment: there is no such a property fir checkboxes[0]. { checkboxes[0]->value() }

Comment: forgot astersisk in QVector<QCheckBox*> Value was only for example. You need to call one of checkBoxes methods, like setChecked. Edited the answer.